# Linq to Entity Birthday Comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I have the requirement to create a query using Linq to Entities where the birthday must fall within 2 days ago and the next 30 days.

The following returns nothing:

```
DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
int twoDaysAgoDay = twoDaysAgo.Day;
int twoDaysAgoMonth = twoDaysAgo.Month;
DateTime MonthAway = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
int monthAwayDay = MonthAway.Day;
int monthAwayMonth = MonthAway.Month;
var bdays = from p in db.Staffs where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.BirthDate) > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(twoDaysAgo) &&
                     EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.BirthDate) < EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(MonthAway)
                    orderby p.BirthDate select p;
return bdays;
```

The problem I'm having is that I need something where if the birthday falls from 11/3 to 12/5, it should return it.  The reason it fails because the birthdays include the Year.  However, when I use something like:

```
p.BirthDate.Value.Month
```

I receive the error that this isn't support with Linq to Entities.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Year-wrapping independent solution:

```
void Main()
{
    var birthdays = new List<DateTime>();
    birthdays.Add(new DateTime(2013, 11, 08));
    birthdays.Add(new DateTime(2012, 05, 05));
    birthdays.Add(new DateTime(2014, 05, 05));
    birthdays.Add(new DateTime(2005, 11, 08));
    birthdays.Add(new DateTime(2004, 12, 31));


    foreach(var date in birthdays.Where(x => x.IsWithinRange(twoDaysAgo, MonthAway))){
      Console.WriteLine(date);
    }           
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static bool IsWithinRange(this DateTime @this, DateTime lower, DateTime upper){
        if(lower.DayOfYear > upper.DayOfYear){
            return (@this.DayOfYear > lower.DayOfYear || @this.DayOfYear < upper.DayOfYear);
        } 

        return (@this.DayOfYear > lower.DayOfYear && @this.DayOfYear < upper.DayOfYear);
    }
}
```

Output with

```
DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
DateTime MonthAway = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

8/11/2013 0:00:00
8/11/2005 0:00:00
```

Output with

```
DateTime twoDaysAgo = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25);
DateTime MonthAway = new DateTime(2013, 01, 05);

31/12/2004 0:00:00
```

Comment: Does that work around year boundaries? ie on 31st December will it correctly return the person whose birthday is 1st January?

Comment: @Chris: See the updated solution. Thanks for bringing this to my attention

Comment: I think DayOfYear will cause a problem on a leap year.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted a linq solution?, it is tagged linq.

Comment: Is `DateTime.DayOfYear` supported by Linq to Entities?

Comment: @Harrison: I've shortened it to use LINQ. You won't get around the extension method, but that doesn't interfere with the LINQ requirement. Kaf: could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't think this will work for a Linq to Entities query. It'll probably fail on that it can find no SQL translation for `IsWithinRange`.

Comment: @Magnus: very possible indeed. In that case I have no better solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the value of the year, what about using `DayOfYear` function ?

```
var bdays = from p in db.Staffs 
            where EntityFunctions.DayOfYear(p.BirthDate) > EntityFunctions.DayOfYear(twoDaysAgo) &&
                  EntityFunctions.DayOfYear(p.BirthDate) < EntityFunctions.DayOfYear(MonthAway)
            orderby p.BirthDate select p;
```

Comment: Does that work around year boundaries? ie on 31st December will it correctly return the person whose birthday is 1st January?

Comment: I guess that a simple workaround to this is to replace `&&` by `||` if `twoDaysAgo.DayOfYear > MonthAway.DayOfYear`, to get a date after 31st december or before 1st february

Comment: This might not work if `BirthDate` is in a leap year.

Comment: Change it to "OR" logic and you'll return everything since you'll be saying the equivalent of "everything before tomorrow or after yesterday" which will be everything. This kind of question is sadly very tricky due to the year boundaries, leap years and so on. I should add that I don't know a particularly neat solution myself, I just know the pitfalls. :(

Comment: `EntityFunctions.DayOfYear` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can change all the years to now since year is irrelevant and then you can check it this way

```
        DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
        DateTime monthAway = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
        List<DateTime> checkDates = new List<DateTime>
        { new DateTime(2011, 11, 3), new DateTime(2011, 12, 5), new DateTime(2011, 12, 6), new DateTime(2011, 11, 2) };
        checkDates = checkDates.Select(x => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, x.Month, x.Day)).ToList();
        var bdays = from p in checkDates
                    where (p >= twoDaysAgo && p <= monthAway) ||
                          (p>= twoDaysAgo.AddYears(-1) && p <= monthAway.AddYears(-1))
                    orderby p
                    select p;
```

This results in

```
11/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

This also works with the following list of dates when today is `new DateTime(2013, 12, 31)`

```
List<DateTime> checkDates = new List<DateTime>
            { new DateTime(2011, 12, 29), new DateTime(2011, 12, 28), new DateTime(2011, 1, 30), new DateTime(2011, 2, 2) };
```

Giving the results

```
1/30/2013 12:00:00 AM
12/29/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you add the the nr. of years from the birthdate to today?
Something like:
(untested)

```
var now        = DateTime.Now;
var twoDaysAgo = now.AddDays(-2); 
var monthAway  = now.Now.AddDays(30)   

var bdays = 
        from p in db.Staffs 
        let bDay = EntityFunctions.AddYears(p.BirthDate,
                     EntityFunctions.DiffYears(now, p.BirthDate))
        where 
           bDay > twoDaysAgo && 
           bDay < monthAway
        orderby p.BirthDate 
        select p;
```